# Architecture/technology for implementing Management console

Tags: architecture, python, rest, sockets

I'm having a distributed environment which include several machines under the same network , which are being controlled by another computer in another network which is also running a UI for doing the operations.
I want to be able to produce some simple parallel interface for being able to do maintenance on these machines.
I wonder what are my options to do so, as I want a simple  management console with UI.

1. Maybe implementing using sockets, sending json messages over the connection.
2. Maybe implement a kind of http server in each machine that will get the messages and act accordingly.

Can you please advise what other possibilities you have in mind and which are  the most suitable in your opinion.
I'm using python, and I prefer python oriented solutions.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260)**

Comment: This question is not specific as how to parse json string in Language A, its a question to help me find a direction for my problem.
If not asked here where do you expect it to be asked?

Comment: @gnat: Don't you think that this is a legitimate question?

Comment: why are you building something from scratch? There are severak quality tools available to do this.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I don't know them, can you specify their names or at least the criteria for search in google to find them?

Comment: See https://github.com/saltstack/salt, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing any form of remote-access will do really, but I would recommend putting a webserver in each process to allow remote control. The reason is partly because its easy to use standards-based comms here (ie a REST interface is easy to implement, easy to call, and easy to build services like security on top of) but also because it allows you to build a web UI into each process as well, so you could connect to each individual process via a browser and let it display a page with the same control functionality as you'd expose as a REST API.

That way you can control each process individually and control them all via a master control program.

Note that you will also have to implement some form of process discovery, unless you want to have to manually configure the location of each process.